# 2018 tgb tapo (202) engine turns over but won't fire up

Tags: small-engine, cranks-wont-run, scooter

tgb tapo rs 50 I have spark and fuel cock seems to work, iv'e also removed carb and cleaned it wondering if
i need to remove inlet manifold and check the reeds

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.